# Loading multiple splitviewcontroller detail views with performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I have 3 detail views I'm trying to load from my splitviewcontroller master views.  All of this was setup via storyboard in ios 5 and XCode 4.2. Detail view A is it's own class.  Detail view C is a subclass of detail view B.

The master is actually a TabBarViewController.

- Tab A segues to a UITableViewController (connected to master A) that segues to another UITableViewController (connected to master B)
- Tab B seques to a UITableViewController (connected to master C) as well

Is there a fundamental flaw in my design, trying to switch the detail views with performSegueWithIdentifier?

I eventually get a sigabort that isn't helpful to the newbie I am.

Here's what's happening:

- Start in master A - detail A displays fine
- Switch to master B - detail B displays fine
- Switch back to master A - detail A displays fine again
- Switch again to master B - sigabort when finishing the segue to detail B

I haven't hooked up detail C yet.  I want to switch to detail C from all masters and even details A and B.

The sigabort happens when exiting the prepareForSegue.  Each prepareForSegue seems to be doing what I think it should.  This is all happening in landscape mode in the simulator.

I've spent a lot of time searching stackoverflow, reading the docs, and looking at examples.  I'm trying to make my storyboard reflect the connections between views and thought performSegueWithIdentifier was a natural way to transition between detail views when the master view changed.

What am I not understanding?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ImageVC"]) {
        // Get a pointer to the dictionary at the currently selected row index
        NSDictionary *photoDictionary = [self.photoList objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        //        NSLog(@"%@", photoDictionary);

        // Set up the photo descriptions in the PhotoDescriptionViewController
        [[segue destinationViewController] setPhotoDictionary:photoDictionary];
    } else if ([segue.identifier hasSuffix:@"MapVC"]) {
        if ([self splitViewMapViewController]) {
            [self splitViewMapViewController].annotations = [self mapAnnotations];
            [self splitViewMapViewController].delegate = self;
        } else {
            [[segue destinationViewController] setAnnotations:[self mapAnnotations]];
            [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"Super class:%@", [self superclass]);
    NSLog(@"Class:%@", [self superclass]);

    if ([self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject]) { // in a split controller, load detail view
        if ([self isMemberOfClass:[PhotoListTableViewController class]]) {
#if TEST > 0
            NSLog(@"Segue to PhotoListMapVC");
#endif
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PhotoListMapVC" sender:self];
        } else if ([self isKindOfClass:[PhotoListTableViewController class]]) {
#if TEST > 0
            NSLog(@"Segue to RecentsMapVC");
#endif
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"RecentsMapVC" sender:self];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"PhotoListTableViewController:viewWillAppear unexpected class %@", [self class]);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code for `prepareForSegue:` and `performSegueWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: @jonkroll, don't know if it's the proper way to respond to your request but I edited the original question in order to format the code block.

Comment: I did a little more debugging today.  The last activity I see in on the list of threads is where I'm attempting to set an image in cellForRowAtIndexPath that was returned from a background downloading queue.  The transition between my master views is handled by segues setup in storyboard.  I assumed the previous master tableview would remain in memory until no longer referenced.  Sorry if I'm not using proper terminology here.

Comment: I would still like to know if using segues this way is valid.  As to the sigabort, I've asked for an answer in a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046424/